# Contour Integral involving hyperbolic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to evaluate:

> $\displaystyle\oint_C \frac{e^{4z}-1}{\cosh(z)-2\sinh(z)}\,\mathrm dz$

where $C$ is a unit circle in the complex plane and $z=x+iy$.

---

I did not find any singular point of the integrand within $|z|<=1$ and hence the integral must be zero.

($\tanh(z)=2$ gives $z=1.15\ldots$ which is greater than 1).

The answer given is $\dfrac{-8}{\sqrt{3}}$.

I tried to modify the integrand by substituting exponential forms of $\cosh$ and $\sinh$, but did not made much progress.

Help is solicited.

Comment: The equation should not be $\tanh(z)=2$, but rather $\tanh(z)=\dfrac12$.

Comment: That is a ridiculous error on my part. Thank you for correcting.

Comment: still I did not get $-8/\sqrt{3}$

Answer (score 1):

The equation should not be $\tanh(z)=2$, but rather $\tanh(z)=\dfrac12$, which would give $z=\dfrac12\log(1.5)+\dfrac{\log(2)}2=0.549\ldots$ as the singularity.

Then you should be able to continue by using [Residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem).